# Missing optional dependency 'tables' in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, library, python-3.7

When we run a Python script as an action in QGIS, we get an error as shown below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 17, in 
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 397, in read_hdf
    store = HDFStore(path_or_buf, mode=mode, errors=errors, **kwargs)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 518, in __init__
    tables = import_optional_dependency("tables")
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\_optional.py", line 92, in import_optional_dependency
    raise ImportError(msg) from None
ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'tables'.  Use pip or conda to install tables.
```

We installed the tables and we have tried to add the paths that QGIS is using from Environment Variables like in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58479748/missing-optional-dependency-tables-in-pandas-to-hdf) but nothing has changed. Unfortunately, I do not know how to use conda while creating an action in QGIS.

We have already installed the required packages in OSGeo4W Shell and did not get an error/warning message.

```
C:\>pip install tables
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: tables in c:\users\semiha - pc\appdata\roaming\py
thon\python37\site-packages (3.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numexpr>=2.6.2 in c:\users\semiha - pc\appdata\ro
aming\python\python37\site-packages (from tables) (2.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.3 in c:\progra~1\qgis3~1.16\apps\pytho
n37\lib\site-packages (from tables) (1.19.1)
```

What can we do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that the user profile python package directory (`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\roaming\python\python39\site-packages`) is not being added to the python search path for Qgis. I don't know how to fix that, but a workaround is to run OSGeo4W Shell as administrator before running pip, so that packages are installed in the system directory. You probably have to uninstall the user profile package first.

```
:: run OSGeo4W Shell as administrator, then:
pip uninstall tables
pip install tables
```